Creating a constrained TypeVar from Union
Running mypy on the following code yields no issues.
from typing import TypeVar

S = TypeVar("S", int, float, complex)

def func(x: list[S], m: S) -> list[S]:
    return [val * m for val in x]

out1: list[int] = func([1, 2, 3], 4)
out2: list[complex] = func([1., 2., 3.], 4.)

But the following code
from typing import TypeVar

Number = int | float | complex
S = TypeVar("S", bound=Number)

def func(x: list[S], m: S) -> list[S]:
    return [val * m for val in x]

out1: list[int] = func([1, 2, 3], 4)
out2: list[complex] = func([1., 2., 3.], 4.)

reports
y.py:7: error: List comprehension has incompatible type List[Union[int, float, complex]]; expected List[S]  [misc]
y.py:7: error: Unsupported operand types for * (likely involving Union)  [operator]

To avoid mypy issues, I think I need to create a constrained TypeVar from the Union (that I am importing from another package and therefore is in principle outside of my control). Is there a way to achieve it? Is there another way (without #type: ignore) to avoid getting a mypy issue?

Just because the union contains the same types you want in a constrained type variable doesn't mean they have anything in common. Unions and constrained type variables serve two very different puprposes; if you need a constrained type variable, define the one you need. You might consider expanding the question to indicate why you think you need a constrained type variable, or why you think it needs to be created from an external union.

@chepner Thanks for writing back. I understand that a bound and constrained types are different. What was not clear to me from the documentation is that S is solved for each appearance for a bound type but not for constrained type. i.e. I am saying def func(x: list[S], m: S) -> list[S]: not def func(x: list[S1], m: S2) -> list[S3]: So S should be the same for x, m and the return value.

Unfortunately, no.
Currently (Python 3.14), there are two ways to create a constrained TypeVar:
# 1. The TypeVar class
from typing import TypeVar
T = TypeVar('T', Constraint1, Constraint2)
def f(v: T) -> T: ...

# 2. PEP 695 syntax
 def f[T: (Constraint1, Constraint2)](v: T) -> T: ...

Both require a hardcoded set of fixed, non-parametrizable constraints. This means the following does not work:
(playground: Pyright)
def make_func[T1, T2, T3](v: T1 | T2 | T3):
    def func[T: (T1, T2, T3)](x: list[T], m: T) -> list[T]:
        #       ^^^^^^^^^^^^ error
        return [val * m for val in x]

    return func

from library import NumericUnion  # int | float | complex

v: NumericUnion = 0
func = make_func(v)  # func: Unknown/Any

